# Enable tomcat failed: Invalid section header '[Unit] Description=Apache Tomcat'

Tags: java, tomcat

I am trying to enable the tomcat server by default. I followed [this](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-9-on-ubuntu-18-04/) method for installation of tomcat 9. my tomcat.service file looks like,

```
[Unit] Description=Apache Tomcat
After=syslog.target network.target
[Service] Type=forking
Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.8
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.8
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom'
WorkingDirectory=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.8
ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/bin/shutdown.sh
User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
UMask=0007
RestartSec=10
Restart=always
[Install] WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I checked my tomcat server which is running on the port 8080 `https://localhost:8080`. But I am unable to enable the Tomcat server.

The command `sudo systemctl enable tomcat` returns following error.

```
● tomcat.service
   Loaded: error (Reason: Bad message)
   Active: inactive (dead)

พ.ค. 11 14:35:04 portal-gic systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service:1: Invalid section header '[Unit] Description=Apache Tomcat'
พ.ค. 11 14:35:05 portal-gic systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service:1: Invalid section header '[Unit] Description=Apache Tomcat'
พ.ค. 11 14:35:10 portal-gic systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service:1: Invalid section header '[Unit] Description=Apache Tomcat'
พ.ค. 11 14:43:02 portal-gic systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service:1: Invalid section header '[Unit] Description=Apache Tomcat'
พ.ค. 11 14:43:55 portal-gic systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service:1: Invalid section header '[Unit] Description=Apache Tomcat'
พ.ค. 11 14:46:02 portal-gic systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service:1: Invalid section header '[Unit] Description=Apache Tomcat'
พ.ค. 11 14:47:53 portal-gic systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service:1: Invalid section header '[Unit] Description=Apache Tomcat'
พ.ค. 12 19:22:44 portal-gic systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service:1: Invalid section header '[Unit] Description=Apache Tomcat'
พ.ค. 12 19:23:55 portal-gic systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service:1: Invalid section header '[Unit] Description=Apache Tomcat'
พ.ค. 12 19:25:17 portal-gic systemd[1]: /etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service:1: Invalid section header '[Unit] Description=Apache Tomcat'
```

Comment: Add a line break in between `[Unit]` and `Description=Apache Tomcat`. I believe all the `[...]` section headers need to be on their own lines. More info [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15348/writing-basic-systemd-service-files).

Comment: I already tried. but no luck. It still showing the same error

Comment: Thank you for your help. You are right. after doing that it popups the error in `[Service]` line. as @tekson answered, I need to make changes on three lines, and run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`. After that finally, I solved my problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as @andreswjames said, the error is arising through first line. And you should break `[Unit]` and `Description=Apache Tomcat` line. Also do same for the `[Service]` and `[Install]` line. The final output will looks like this,

```
[Unit] 
Description=Apache Tomcat
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service] 
Type=forking
Environment=JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64
Environment=CATALINA_PID=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/temp/tomcat.pid
Environment=CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.8
Environment=CATALINA_BASE=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.8
Environment='CATALINA_OPTS=-Xms512M -Xmx1024M -server -XX:+UseParallelGC'
Environment='JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom'
WorkingDirectory=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.8
ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/bin/startup.sh
ExecStop=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.8/bin/shutdown.sh
User=tomcat
Group=tomcat
UMask=0007
RestartSec=10
Restart=always

[Install] 
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After editing this file you should run following command,

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

This will help the system to recognize our changes.

After that you can enable and check the status of tomcat.

```
sudo systemctl enable tomcat
sudo systemctl status tomcat
```

Hope this will helps you!

Comment: Ohh, Thank you very much this is really working now.

Comment: Thanks a lot, who knew formatting is so important..